# Does Emacs support basic unicode sub-properties for regular expressions?

Tags: regex, emacs

EmacsWiki[1] contains the regular expression syntax used in Emacs. My question is, is this a non-exhaustive reference? That is, does Emacs support more advanced properties like Perl's `\p{Currency_Symbol}` (shortened `\p{Sc}`) that are just not listed there? If so, where can one find a list of all symbols that are supported in Emacs regular expressions?

[1] http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression

**Edit**

I'm guessing the list is non-exhaustive based on the listing of `[[syntax_classes]]` that seems to be fairly short and does not include e.g. `[[:lower:]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitive guide is always the Emacs manual

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html

There are (at least) two ways to experiment with regular expressions in Emacs visually:

- `M-x re-builder`
- [visual-regexp](https://github.com/benma/visual-regexp.el)

Comment: Good source. Should have searched it before asking. Thanks for the pointer!